# why did the width/height of viewport change from int to float in glViewportIndexed

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

glViewport: width/height are integers (which are pixels).

But glViewportIndexed has these values in float. What are the advantages of having them in float. My understanding is based on the fact that pixels are always integers.

Comment: Well, that is not exactly true. Pixel locations are fixed-point, you may have heard the term sub-pixel precision at some point... 8-bit sub-pixel precision means that you can actually address regions of space 1/256th the size of a pixel. Many things (e.g. primitive coverage) would not work correctly with 0-bit sub-pixel precision.

Comment: Check the value of `gl_FragCoord.x` in a fragment shader sometime (those coordinates are in window-space). Notice how it is not restricted to integer coordinates? You sample from the center of a fragment (single sample rasterization) and by the default convention that center is offset by a half-integer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, ok got it. But then why is glViewport have x,y,w,h in integers? Does it apply the viewport transformation to all the viewports or only the first viewport.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, 2nd question: if VIEWPORT_SUBPIXEL_BITS  returns value 4, then will gl_FragCoord.xy have values with offsets (0,0) (0.5, 0) (0, 0.5) and (0.5, 0.5) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may look like the `glViewport*()` calls specify pixel rectangles. But if you look at the details of the OpenGL rendering pipeline, that's not the case. They specify the parameters for the **viewport transformation**. This is the transformation that maps normalized device coordinates (NDC) to window coordinates.

If `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` are your specified viewport dimensions, `xNdc` and `yNdc` your NDC coordinates, the viewport transformation can be written like this:

```
xWin = x + 0.5 * (xNdc + 1.0) * w;
yWin = y + 0.5 * (yNdc + 1.0) * h;
```

In this calculation, `xNdc` and `yNdc` are of course floating point values, in their usual (-1.0, 1.0) range. I do not see any good reason why `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` should be restricted to integer values in this calculation. This transformation is applied before rasterization, so there is no need to round anything to pixel units.

Not needing integer values for the viewport dimensions could even be practically useful. Say you have a window of size 1000x1000, and you want to render 9 sub-views of equal size in the window. There's no reason for the API to stop you from doing what's most natural: Make each sub-view the size 333.3333x333.3333, and use those sizes for the parameters of `glViewport()`.

If you look at `glScissorIndexed()` for comparison, you will notice that it still takes integer coordinates. This makes complete sense, because `gScissor()` does in fact specify a region of pixels in the window, unlike `glViewport()`.

Comment: So if i subdivide a 1000x1000 into 9 viewports with size 333.3333x333.3333 each, and now i want to scissor out the first viewport. I specify (333,333) in glScissorIndexed(), will i see a tear in the final screen depending on precision of VIEWPORT_SUBPIXEL_BITS  ?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your new questions in comments would have proved difficult, so even though Reto Koradi has already answered your question I will attempt to answer them here.

---

> @AndonM.Coleman, ok got it. But then why is glViewport have x,y,w,h in integers?

Probably because back when `glViewport (...)` was created, there was no programmable pipeline. Even back then, sub-pixel offsets were sometimes used (particularly when trying to match rasterization coverage rules for things like `GL_LINES` and `GL_TRIANGLES`) but they had to be applied to the transformation matrices.

Now you can do the same thing using the viewport transform instead, which is a heck of a lot simpler (4 scalars needed for the viewport) than passing a giant `mat4` (16 scalars) into a Geometry Shader.

---

> Does it apply the viewport transformation to all the viewports or only the first viewport.

#### From the [`GL_ARB_viewport_array`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/viewport_array.txt) extension specification:

> > **`glViewport`** sets the parameters for all viewports to the same values
> >         and is equivalent (assuming no errors are generated) to:
> >
> > ```
> >   for (GLuint i = 0; i < GL_MAX_VIEWPORTS; i++)
> >     glViewportIndexedf(i, 1, (GLfloat)x, (GLfloat)y, (GLfloat)w, (GLfloat)h);
> > ```

---

> @AndonM.Coleman, 2nd question: if VIEWPORT_SUBPIXEL_BITS returns value 4, then will gl_FragCoord.xy have values with offsets (0,0) (0.5, 0) (0, 0.5) and (0.5, 0.5) ?

If you have 4-bits of sub-pixel precision then what that means is that vertex positions after transformation will be snapped to a position <sup>1</sup>/<sub>16</sub><sup>th</sup> the width of a pixel. GL actually does not require ***any*** sub-pixel bits here; in such a case your vertex positions after transformation into window-space would jump by 1 pixel distances at a time and you would see a lot of "sparklies" as you move anything in the scene.

#### This animation demonstrates "sparklies"; it originated from [here](http://www.minddesk.com/vanilla/index.php?p=/discussion/636/noise-artifacts-on-models-with-qubicle-unite-in-unity-/p1):

[image]

See the white dots as the camera moves? If you do not have enough sub-pixel precision when you transform your vertices, the rasterizer has difficulty properly dealing with edges that are ***supposed*** to be adjacent. The technical term for this is T-Junction Error, but I am quite fond of the word "sparkly" ;)

As for `gl_FragCoord.xy`, no that is actually unaffected by your sub-pixel precision during vertex transform. That is the sample location within your fragment (usually aligned to **... + 0.5** as you point out), and it is unrelated to vertex processing.